# TEMP environment variable occasionally changes its value

Tags: windows-7, process, environment-variables

I have Windows 7 Pro x64.

During the last one or two weeks, it happens sometimes to me that various applications cannot write to temporary directory. I've found that this is because the TEMP environment variable is set to the system value (`C:\Windows\TEMP` usually, I have it set differently), and not to the user value (`B:\Users\%USERNAME%\Temp` in my case). Also the `explorer.exe` process has TEMP set incorrectly, when this problem occurs.

Originally I thought that the incorrect TEMP value is set during winlogon, but it turns out this is not always the case. It's also important to say that this happens with several user profiles on the same computer, not only with my own profile.

Yesterday, when this happened again, I restarted the computer, logged in and checked that the `explorer.exe` process has this TEMP variable set correctly. Then I started several other applications, all have TEMP set correctly too.
But today, after waking up the notebook from sleep, `explorer.exe` has incorrect TEMP value again, and hence every other newly started application inherits it! Its evidently still the same process as yesterday, as its a parent process for most applications, including those that were started yesterday and still have TEMP set correctly! I'm perplexed :-(.

**Questions:** How can anything like this happen? What can this strange behaviour be caused by? How to solve the problem?

The problem is frustrating as I always have to close everything and perform logout&login.

**Remarks:**

- I use ProcessExplorer to see how the current environment of individual processes looks like.
- I don't thing the memory gets corrupted. Because then TEMP would be filled with a nonsense, not with the valid system TEMP value.
- There's plenty of space on the disks.
- Nor I think that my profile is corrupted. Because the same I have notices with other profiles as well, and it doesn't happen always.

Comment: Read over this for an explanation: http://environmentvariables.org/Temp maybe it will help clarify for you some. Depending on the security context of something running that uses that variable, one or the other may be used per the correlated alias/environmental variable pointer. So if it runs as `SYSTEM` for example it may use `C:\Windows\TEMP` whereas using as a user account may use the profile temp path.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I don't see there anything useful. In particular, how is it possible that explorer.exe process changes its TEMP value during time? And how to prevent that?

Comment: Set a different variable name other than `%TEMP%` and use it instead: `SET dTemp=%SYSTEMROOT%\TEMP` Then use `%dTemp%` in the rest of your script instead. Quick workaround I suppose in terms of how to prevent other than controlling the runtime/execution time security context of whatever is executing the process that uses the `%TEMP%` variable.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I'm not having a problem with a script but with Windows. Applications in Windows have problems when they try to write to the TEMP folder, because the TEMP variable in their environment is set to wrong location. Not my script (I'm writing none currently).

Comment: Check your system variables: you will probably find that `TEMP` is set to the system default in the system variables and to your setting in the user variables (`PC` -> `Properties` -> `Advanced System Settings` -> `Advanced` tab -> `Environment Variables...` button). How are you checking Explorer's `TEMP` value? System processes (eg launched by a service) will use the system `TEMP` setting, while user processes will use your user `TEMP`.

Comment: @AFH: The TEMP var is defined both for users and system, but with different values. I've checked it. But also, if incorrect setting was the case, it would be wrong always, not only sometimes. To check the process enviroment, I use ProcessExplorer: double-click on the process, and there is an Environment tab in the dialog.

Comment: Process Explorer will show you the program's parent in tree view: follow up the tree to see what scheduled it in each case and where the `TEMP` setting changes.

Comment: So they are using the `SYSTEM` security context probably then and thus they'd need to use user level security context instead when the "apps" that use this value are launched rather than `SYSTEM`. Or per each app's configurations, maybe you can set it to use a static path rather than the environmental environment.  What "apps" are experiencing this problem? You can also grant access to the `%SYSTEMROOT%\Temp` to everyone potentially I suppose if that's an option and the location it uses and gets denied access. Just suggesting quick workarounds in case that'll suffice for your needs.

Comment: @AFH: I know :-). The ultimate parent is `explorer.exe`. But this is the mystery I was describing in the question - after logon its TEMP was set correctly, but later it has changed. Which is what I don't understand, how its even possible. For details, please see the question, I tried to describe that there.

Comment: Any program can change its environment with the `setenv()` system call. What I can't answer is why it would want to change `TEMP`, unless it makes checks on the target directory and finds it does not meet some criterion, such as free space.

Comment: @AFH: Would `explorer.exe` do the checks and change the TEMP variable accordingly? I'll try to think on a reason why would it do that in my case, currently I see none. And it wasn't doing anything like this before, as far as I remember.

Comment: @McDonalds: Forinstance my file manager, or NetBeans IDE. Apart of the Windows Explorer. Simply any app that was started by the Windows Explorer while it had incorrect TEMP value.

Comment: I've never known Explorer do this. Are you sure that there isn't a second copy running in the system environment? Make a note of the PID in each case.

Comment: @AFH: I'm sure. Because this `explorer.exe` process is **the** parent of other processes.